# Alternative lattice plot using ggplot2 for density

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I wanted an alternative plot using ggplot2 for the one generated by the code below:

```
library(lattice)
x<-rnorm(1000)

plot.new()
densityplot(x, main="Density",ylab="",
   panel=function(x, ...){
     panel.densityplot(x,col="black", ...)
     panel.abline(v=.5,col="gray")
   }
)
```

[image]

I need sample at the bottom of the plot (like bars at the right of these plots [enter link description here](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/321)). I've just found some plots similar to:

```
library(ggplot)

x1=seq(x)
data1<-data.frame(x1,x)
m <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = x))
m + geom_density(alpha=.3, fill="black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x<-rnorm(1000)
x<-as.data.frame(x)

require(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(x,aes(x=x))
g <- g + geom_density()
g <- g + geom_vline(xintercept = .5)
g <- g + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=0),shape=1,size=5)
g <- g + theme_bw()
g
```

UPDATED to include comment of OP - note how the geom_point with y=1 will create the sample on the axis.

This will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something like a bar at the bottom with sample. Something like the bar at right of theses plots http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/321

Comment: Ah I overlooked the observations on the x-axis. Updated the code correspondingly and included an illustration.

Comment: You're welcome - notice how this resembles the observations on the unit circles in the radial plot yesterday. The structure is fairly similar and illustrates the universality of the grammar of graphics. Furthermore, you can quickly change to a histogram instead of the density plot: Just replace geom_density by geom_histogram.

Comment: Instead of `geom_point` with custom aesthetics, you can use `geom_rug` which is designed for that purpose.